# Firestore - query all documents which field matches values in a list (like SQL IN)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a book collection for example, each book has 'genre' field. How to query all books which genre is "fantasy" or "historical"? Like SQL `SELECT * FROM book WHERE genre in ("fantasy", "historical")`. Pretty usual SQL query as my opinion.

I found [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321) feature request in GitHub, which isn't resolved yet. The Firestore [documentation says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations): "Logical OR queries aren't supported". So, I cannot do such simple query in Firestore? What is a workaround? Should I query each genre separately and join the result?

Note, that I found similar questions like "How to get multiple documents by set of ids?", but not about custom properties. For ids, there is 'getAll()' method in the js admin sdk for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported in firestore as you correctly identified. You can send two separate queries and merge the results locally. This is how it needs to be done unfortunately. If yours is a simple usecase, sending two separate requests shouldn't be a problem.

However, have a look at `rxfire` package which is officially supported by firebase. Note that it doesn't support `or` queries per se but with the help of `rxjs`, it makes such tasks easier to manage. Here's an excerpt from the link below on what it can do:

> Firebase provides realtime streams and async callbacks to do all sorts
>   of awesome things in your app. Getting data from one realtime stream
>   is easy enough, but what if you want to join it from another?
>   Combining multiple async streams of data can get complex. At Firebase,
>   we wanted to help simplify things, so we created a new JavaScript
>   library: RxFire.

Link to introductory blogpost: [RxFire](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/09/introducing-rxfire-easy-async-firebase.html)

Comment: Ok, I just upset, that such simple query becomes more complex. Thank you for `rxjs` suggestion, I really like it, but it is Android project, and I use Kotlin coroutines instead of rx, and It is magic! The Code is easier and more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that now you can query the collection to return what you need using the

> whereIn

operator.

Read documentation here: [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

For example (dart language)

```
final booksRef = db.collection("books");
final cities = booksRef.where("genre", whereIn: ["fantasy", "historical"]);
```